# Gradle: How to include Java project flavor dependency resources into Android APK?

Tags: java, android, resources, dependencies, gradle

I have some resouces-only Java projects with build.gradle(s):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

and directory structure:

```
flavor1/
  src/
    main/
      resources/
        assets/
          file1.png
flavor2/
  src/
    main/
      resources/
        assets/
          file1.png
```

and an another project (this time Android) with build.gradle:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
  }

  productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
      packageName "com.mydomain.flavor1"
    }

    flavor2 {
      packageName "com.mydomain.flavor2"
    }
  }

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      res.srcDirs = ['res']
      assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
    flavor1 {
      res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1']
      assets.srcDirs = ['assets-flavor1']
    }
    flavor2 {
      res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1']
      assets.srcDirs = ['assets-flavor2']
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  flavor1Compile project(':flavor1')
  flavor2Compile project(':flavor2')
}
```

with directory structure:

```
android_project/
  assets/
  assets-flavor1/
  assets-flavor2/
  res/
  res-flavor1/
  res-flavor2/
  src/
    main/
      java/
        com/
          ...
```

The problem is that resources from plain Java projects :flavor1 and :flavor2 are not included into resulting APK. If I include them as global dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(:flavor1)
}
```

they are included in the APK fine.

The reason of those plain Java projects is that they are resources both for Android project flavors and other projects (iOS, HTML, Java, that are not described in the question) so I can't include them directly in Android project assets.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add path to Java project resources folder explicitly?

```
flavor1 {
  res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1']
  assets.srcDirs = ['assets-flavor1', '$java-project-root/flavor1/src/main/resources/assets']
}
```

It is not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: This does work! Though relative or absolute paths has to be used so I edited your post. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately this breaks import to Android Studio and IntelliJ with error: Can't register given path of type 'SOURCE' because it's out of content root. Any clue how to fix that?

Comment: It's fixed in Android Studio 0.5! Hurray!

Answer (score 1):

Each flavor creates an associated dependency configuration object, so you can do:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile project(':flavor1')
    flavor2Compile project(':flavor2')
}
```

This will package the right assets in the right variant.

Comment: I do, see my question thoroughly. This does work for Java projects but not for Android projects. Namely the project dependency is used (sources, etc.) but the resource files are not included in resulting APK.

Comment: From the other answer, I gather that you want them as assets and not resources (which is not clear from your questions). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I thouth that in case of Android they are synonyms.

Comment: Do dependencies based on flavors work for library projects as well?